# Bettercap TLS handshake phase information

Tags: tls, client, bettercap

I wanted to know if bettercap has a feature that allows to view TLS handshake phase information (as Wireshark does), for example the "Client Hello" ?

Comment: Have you checked the manual?

Comment: @multithr3at3d yes but it doesn't say anything about the TLS handshake

Comment: @multithr3at3d do you know anything about it?

Comment: Not really. I suppose opening Wireshark as well is not an option in your scenario?